# Upper bound for sum of powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convex-analysis

I have a sequence of positive real numbers $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I was wondering if one can find an upper bound of the type

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i^k} \leq f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i} \right)$$

where $f$ is a smooth function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(y)=y^k$ works.  If you expand the $k^{\text{th}}$ power of the sum on the right, you get all the terms on the left plus a bunch of positive cross terms.